# Maximum of Independent Gamma random variables?

Tags: probability, order-statistics, gumbel-distribution

Suppose $Y=\max\{X_1, X_2,\dots,X_N\}$ where all $X_i$ are independent and  follows gamma distribution. I know that extreme value theory deals with maximum of random variables. Can anybody tell me, hopefully with reference, $Y$ will follow which extreme value distribution (Gumbel, Weibull or Frechet) ?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847595/problem-with-the-expectation-of-a-maximum-of-independent-gamma-distributed-rando) may be helpful.

Comment: Why are we limited to 3 choices?

Comment: @wolfies That's what the theory has found.

Comment: It seems you are looking for the **limit** law (as $N \to \infty$).  Perhaps better to mention that in the question.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Quite the opposite, the question mentions nothing about asymptotic behaviour ... and none of the 3 posited distributions are a valid answer to the question posed.

Comment: @wolfies Indeed, it doesn't, but it created (to me) that impression, exactly because he referred to the three possible asymptotic distributions. So the OP should clarify the point.

Comment: @upol94 As wolfies points out, the correct answer to the question you have posed is "none of the above". If you're seeking asymptotic results you need to make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 9):

The gamma distribution is in the Gumbel domain of attraction.  You can
refer to the book by L. de Haan and A Ferreira, [*Extreme Values Theory,
an Introduction*](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/probability/book/978-0-387-23946-0).
See therein theorem 1.1.8 and exercise 1.7 for its application to the
gamma distribution. Another very useful book even provides explicit
values for the two sequences required in the normalisation:
P. Embrechts, C. Klüppelberg and T. Mikosch [*Modelling Extremal Events
for Inusurance and Finance*](http://www.springer.com/fr/book/9783540609315); This is in section 3.4,
p. 156 in my edition.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from
[David, H. A., & Nagaraja, H. N. (2003). *Order statistics* 3d ed.](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471389269.html), ch 10. p 296

[image]

The "two references that give the most complete and rigorous discussion of the problem" are

[image]

Comment: This answer reads like your justification for saying Frechet is that it has non-negative support.  But the extreme value limit laws are **after** normalisation.  E.g. for the maximum of Exponential random variables (which are non-negative), the limit is Gumbel.

Comment: More precisely, if $X_1, \ldots$ are i.i.d Exp($\lambda$), then you can show (bare hands) that $$\mathbb{P}( \lambda \cdot \max_{i = 1,\ldots,n} X_i \le \ln(n) + x) \to e^{-e^{-x}}$$, and Theorem 10.5.1 applies with $a_n =1/\lambda$, $b_n = \ln(n)/\lambda$.  (Just to clarify-- I have no idea which class the Gamma limits belong to, but it is not as simple as looking at the supports).

Comment: @P.Windridge  Thanks, that's a standard source of confusion (for me that is). I deleted the reference to Frechet while I am digging this.

Comment: Cool, I'll be interested in the answer.  I suspect it is Gumbel, just because the Gamma and Exponential distributions are so closely related... but that's only speculation :)

Comment: @P.Windridge, Thanks, I am also confused on the same point. Is gamma also follow Gumbel distribution ?

Comment: @upol94 the exponential distribution is a special case of the gamma.  So, for some parameters, the limit class is certainly Gumbel... but off the top of my head I don't know whether this holds generally.

Comment: The question does not ask about the asymptotic distribution of $Y$ ... it seeks the distribution of $Y$.

Comment: That's a pretty extensive quote ... and not readable by anyone using a screen reader (as a few of our sight-impaired users do). Could you consider whether you can take a few parts - whatever you need most - and write them as actual quotes rather than screenshots? \[You might be able to make reference to one of these wikipedia articles [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem), [(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory), [(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) for part of it, perhaps.]